# Facebook Login Button Hover Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I create a box that hovers over the bottom right of the page with a Facebook login button?

Comment: This isn't a tutorial service. You will need to work out the basics yourself and ask questions here when you have a real code issue

Answer (score 0):

HTML - put this anywhere in your document and fill with what you need

```
<div id='bottom-right-corner'></div>
```

CSS

```
#bottom-right-corner {
    position: fixed;  /* Pin to the window */
    z-index: 9999; /* Keep on top of all other content */
    bottom: 0px; /* Keep the bottom on the bottom of the page */
    right: 20px; /* Keep the right just away from the right edge */
}
```